# How to include a link in email that opens an Android app if available, but opens the website if not?

Tags: html, javascript, email, hyperlink

In HTML code for an email is there a way to have a fallback URL when a primary URL cannot be handled?

For example:

- Open app when using Android
- Open website when clicking on it on a desktop

I know how to do that in Javascript, but in emails there is no Javascript.